# Google Drive query not retrieving files - only the first time

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive APIs to query on files and retrieve their metadata. When running the app on a device *where it has never been installed before*, the returned MetadataBuffer is empty (as I see from the logcat). *If I uninstall the app and re-install it back*, the same code produces a MetaDataBuffer with the expected Metadata objects. This has happened in every device I have been testing. I am supposing that it has something to do with the local cache. I wonder if I am missing something in my code, or I should eventually file an issue to Google.
Here is the complete code:

```
public void setupClient(boolean noProgress) {
    Log.i("drive", "setup client...");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(parent)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
            .build();        
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {  
        Log.i("drive", "connected");         
        Filter mime = Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, MIME_TYPE);
        Filter trashed = Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false);
        Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(mime)
                .addFilter(trashed)
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient,query).setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
    }

private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {                    
                MetadataBuffer buffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();                                         
                Log.i("drive", String.valueOf(buffer.getCount()));                  
                if (buffer.getCount()>0) {  
                /* this is where it fails:
                   the first time, getCount() is 0. the following times,
                   getCount() is the right number of files in the Drive */
                    Log.i("drive","files found");
                    //do things with metadata...
                } else {                        
                    Log.i("drive","files not found"); 
                    //do other things when there are no files...
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: I have the same issue but I can reproduce it every time the app is intalled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local sync takes a little bit to process. If you make a request before its done, you may get incomplete results.  You can use [requestSync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#requestSync(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) to wait for a sync to have completed.  (Although sometimes this request gets rate limited if there is already a request in progress.  We are working on improving this behavior.)

Comment: requestSync seems to solve the issue. Thank you very much for the hint

Comment: Can you write example how to "requestSync"?

Comment: @Michal Just call `Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(googleApiClient)`. But be warned that the request limit is very limited. If I wait less than a minute between calls I get the error `DriveStatusCodes.DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`. The delay is not documented and makes syncing app data between devices impractical.